# Saving Django Model with OneToOne Relationship Field returns Object has no attribute 'id' error

Tags: django, django-models

I have defined OneToOne Relationship in model b with model a. When i try to save model b i get "Model B : Object has no attribute 'id' " error. How to resolve this issue? What am i missing here.

Models:

```
class ModelA:
  invoicedate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
  amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
  status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='ACTIVE')

  class Meta:
    db_table = "modela"

class ModelB:
  rel = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
  field1 ...

class Meta:
    db_table = "modelb"
```

Method to insert data into models:

```
@transaction.atomic
def methodToInsertData(args):
   new_modela = ModelA(
                  "invoicedate" = "2018-11-05",
                  "amount" = 5000,
                  "status" = "ACTIVE"
                )
    new_modela.save()

   new_modelb = ModelB(
                 rel = new_modela,
                 ...
                )
   new_modelb.save() #This statement throws "object has no attribute id" error
```

ModelA will auto create id as primary key but model B will not have id as primary key instead rel field would be the primary key with OneToOne relationship to Model A.

Any suggestions to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: according to your code, you should not be able to save ModelA, you should have faced `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression` error

Comment: That was just a reference for a date field. I have edited it to InvoiceDate now.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you set the OneToOneField as the model's primary key. Try removing primary_key=True and either explicitly setting another field (uuid or integer) as pk, or simply allowing the model to set its own id.

```
  rel = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Model B's rel is an extension of Model A and rel key must be a primary key.